# Can't get DELL U2717D to display retina quality on macbook pro 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a Dell Monitor U2717D and I tried connecting it to my 13 inch MacBook pro 2017 running MacOS Mojave. I tried using different cables such as 4K HDMI to USB C, DisplayPort to USB C, etc.. but the text never looks as crisp as on Macbook Pro 2017 screen. The resolution is 2560x1440 on the dell and 1440x900 on the mac.

I also tried fixes such as turning on and off font smoothing, etc

```
defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO

defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

Is there a way to make the text look as crisp/sharp on my dell as it is on macbook pro display?

Comment: The max display resolution on that monitor is 2560 x 1440. If you want a high resolution display you will need to look for a monitor that supports 4/5K resolutions.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, that's the max resolution but the laptop resolution is 1440x900 and it's retina.. why can't 2560x1440 display retina quality?

Comment: "Retina" in AppleSpeak is a high DPI setting. I do not believe the Dell display supports HighDPI. The display of the 13-inch 2017 MacBook pro is, "13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2560-by-1600 native resolution at 227 pixels per inch with support for millions of colors." So your quoted resolution is the *effective* resolution of the display.